# How to match features when the number of features of both objects in unequal?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have 2 objects. I get n features from object 1 & m features from object 2.

n!=m

I have to measure the probability that object 1 is similar to object 2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tutorial in the OpenCV website that does this. [Check it out](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html). 
The idea is to get the distances between all those descriptors with a [FlannBasedMatcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?highlight=flannbasedmatcher#FlannBasedMatcher%20%3a%20public%20DescriptorMatcher), get the closest ones, and run RANSAC to find some set of consistent features between the two objects. You don't get a probability, but the number of consistent features, from which you may score how good your detection is, but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the features in the image where features are more.
Set a vector to use the same. There may be multiple matches from among-st that you can choose the highest one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about point feature descriptors, like SIFT, SURF, or FREAK?

In that case there are several strategies.  In all cases you need a distance measure.  For SIFT or SURF you can use the Euclidean distance between the descriptors, or the L1 norm, or the dot product (correlation).  For binary features, like FREAK or BRISK, you typically use the Hamming distance.

Then, one approach, is to simply pick a threshold on the distance.  This is likely to give you many-to-many matches. Another way is to use bipartite graph matching to find the minimum-cost or maximum-weight assignment between the two sets.  A very practical approach is described by [David Lowe](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf), which uses a ratio test to discard ambiguous matches.

Many of these strategies are implemented in the [matchFeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB.